# How to convert integer into datetime in varchar format

Tags: sql-server, datetime, select, ssms-2012

I m getting this error when trying to convert below integer into `datetime` in a  `varchar` format.

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Code:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CAST('200901041421' AS DATETIME))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a space, and a colon. I'm not sure why you want to do this though... present the date in a format on your front end (presentation layer) and keep dates stored as dates or datetime in the database and you won't run into this issue :)

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CAST('20090104 14:21' AS DATETIME))
```

Also, no need to use `MAX` here. That's a waste of storage. Something like this makes more sense.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(24), CAST('20090104 14:21' AS DATETIME), 113)
```

Using a column name...

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(24), CAST(YourColumnName AS DATETIME), 113)
FROM YourTable
```

[You can see other conversions here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: How to configure this if i have about a million of these dates

Comment: Well, i'd use the column name in place of the literal value of course.

Comment: CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),cast( stuff(stuff(p.exitdate,7,8,' '),12,13,':') as datetime),121)

Comment: ah, i see what you were asking now. Stuff would be how i went about it as well